# cannot use SessionLoginBehaviour SSO_WITH_FALLBACK

Tags: java, android, xml, facebook

Even after defining `com.facebook.LoginActivity` in my AndroidManifest.xml file the logcat gives the same error and asks to define `com.facebook.LoginActivity` as activity. I have followed this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2#step2 tutorial.

Here is my `androidmanifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.log"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.log.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.loginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>


</application>

</manifest>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.log;


import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
 private MainFragment mainFragment;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
     if (savedInstanceState == null) {
         // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
         mainFragment = new MainFragment();
         getSupportFragmentManager()
         .beginTransaction()
         .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
         .commit();
     } else {
         // Or set the fragment from restored state info
         mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
         .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
     }
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
  // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
  // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
  int id = item.getItemId();
  if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
   return true;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

 /**
  * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
  */
 public static class MainFragment extends Fragment {

  

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
          ViewGroup container, 
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

      return view;
  }
 }

}
```

`fragment_main.xml file`

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/authButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facebook login activity is `com.facebook.LoginActivity` with a capital 'L'. You're using a lower case l.

Comment: This is what happens when i am coding for a long time and my eyes are about to burst! thanks Shivam Verma ! it works.